# React Component not working with ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this Timer component written with React,that does work with es5, but for some reasons it doesn't with es6..

```
class Timer extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {start: 15}
    }

  tick() {
    this.setState ({start: this.state.start - 1});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  } 

  render() {
    return <h1> Time here:  {this.state.start}</h1>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Need to mention that I'm not too familliar with React, still looking further to improve myself.

Comment: What do you mean it 'doesn't' work?

Comment: @It renders the <Timer />, but the state.start doesn't change..

Comment: You need to bind your functions to this in the constructor. this.tick = this.tick.bind (this);

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind tick

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {start: 15}
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this)
    }
```

Comment: Nvm, I thought that's needed only for an event like onClick. Thanks for clarifying this for me ;)

Comment: @alex1997 Every time you are passing a reference to a method to another function ;)

Comment: Not necessarily every time.  Just anytime where you this is referenced in a function and you expect it to be referencing the current component (in the case of React components)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your your tick function :

```
    class Timer extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {start: 15}
    }

  tick() {
    this.setState ({start: this.state.start - 1});
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  } 

  render() {
    return <h1> Time here:  {this.state.start}</h1>
  }
}

React.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1019/)